# Is Jquery UI 1.11.1 compatible with Jquery 2.1.1?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is JQuery UI compatible with JQuery 2.1.1? I get the error 'TypeError: b is undefined' on FireFox when I try to use them together. Also, I noticed on jsfiddle.net that if you select JQuery 2.1.0 the JQuery UI plugin option is removed - leaving me to wonder.

I have included the following files from JQuery UI - jquery-ui.min.js, jquery-ui.min.css

I am also using bootstrap 3.x

Update: on Chrome I notice the following error on JS console - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok - got the answer - I had an incorrect call to a method called 'draggable' from JQuery UI in my file that was causing the error. to answer my original question - YES - JQuery UI 1.11.1 is compatible with JQuery 2.1.1